# React - state updated in element inspection but not in actual DOM

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm just trying to build a frontend builder React app. Everything goes as expected but not one.

```
const [displayContent, setDisplayContent] = useState(
        props.contentInside.html
    );
```

```
<button
                        onClick={() => {
                            props.changeLanguage("HTML");
                            setDisplayContent(props.contentInside.html);
                        }}
                    >
                        HTML
                    </button>
                    <button
                        onClick={() => {
                            props.changeLanguage("CSS");
                            setDisplayContent(props.contentInside.css);
                        }}
                    >
                        CSS
                    </button>
                    <button
                        onClick={() => {
                            props.changeLanguage("Js");
                            setDisplayContent(props.contentInside.js);
                        }}
                    >
                        Js
                    </button>
```

```
<textarea
                    className="bg-[rgb(20,20,20)] p-2 pt-1 border-[1px] border-t-0 border-yellow-300 border-dashed text-yellow-300"
                    placeholder={placeHolder}
                    defaultValue={displayContent}
                    onChange={props.updateContent}
                ></textarea>
```

See it should work perfect but not yet and idk y.
check these pictures
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfyv9.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUKL8.png)

As you can see in this pic, the content is updated on the element inspection, but not in the actual DOM.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the defaultValue prop in the textarea is causing the issue. The defaultValue prop is only used to set the initial value of the textarea and doesn't update the value of the textarea when the state changes.

You can fix this issue by using the value prop instead of defaultValue. Here's the updated code:

```
<textarea
  className="bg-[rgb(20,20,20)] p-2 pt-1 border-[1px] border-t-0 border-yellow-300 border-dashed text-yellow-300"
  placeholder={placeHolder}
  value={displayContent}
  onChange={props.updateContent}
>
</textarea>
```

By using value instead of defaultValue, the textarea will be updated with the new value whenever displayContent changes.

Comment: yeah, that worked, but I can't edit the values, now. ಥ_ಥ.
textarea should to editable right? user should be able to type in something.
thanks for your help btw. it would be really helpful if you could solve this too.....

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in supun answer you have to use `value` not `defaultValue` to display the value of `displayContent` in the textarea, and the reason why you cannot update it is because each time you type in the textare it is `props.updateContent` that is executed so `displayContent` is the same, therefore, the `onChange` handler should update `displayContent`:

```js
value={displayContent}
onChange={(e) => {setDisplayContent(e.target.value)}}
```